# How do I print to thermal network printers in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, networking, printing

I'm looking for ways to print to a thermal network printer in flutter.
I have found some great plugins, but it seems they all print to a printer that has itself an IP address, not one that is connected to a computer and shared on the network, like \\server\printer1, for instance.
My printer does not have network hardware, it is connected to a computer running Windows, via USB.

Is there a plugin or technique that allows connection to a printer like that, or am I using the plugin incorrectly?
Or is there a way to give a shared printer its own IP address?

As an example, here is what I've tried so far, using the plugin esc_pos_printer

```
  final PosPrintResult res = await printer.connect('192.168.29.94', port: 9100);
  // and also used the IP and shared name of the printer 
  final PosPrintResult res = await printer.connect('\\\\192.168.29.94\\MP-4200 TH', port: 9100);
```

I always get the error : "Error. Printer connection timeout"

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did  you find a solution to your problem ?

Comment: Nope sorry @VDTe

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough experience in developing apps for windows,
but you can use the method-channel to achieve your goals.
here is the reference:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop

I had integrated Zebra Printer using android (java code) if you need any help or demo code please let me know.